# Why is Firefox ESR the standard for Kali Linux?

Tags: kali-linux, firefox

**Why is Firefox ESR the standard for Kali Linux?**

I was getting a new instance of Kali set up; as it was updating, I hovered over the Firefox logo in the sidebar and noticed that it said "Firefox ESR". I guess up until now, I didn't care, but now I am wondering why the "Extended Support Release" Edition is the default browser instead of the normal Firefox Edition. When I went to their [website](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/) it only really says this:

> Is there any difference between Firefox and Firefox ESR?
>
> Firefox and Firefox ESR are extremely similar. Rarely, some features
>   are disabled in ESR for different reasons like stability issues,
>   potential changes in the specifications, etc. Any differences between
>   the regular release and ESR are documented in the release notes of the
>   first ESR release of the cycle.

Does this mean that the 'ESR' Edition is more secure than the Standard Edition? Or does it mean that it allows Kali Linux to adjust its features to the needs of the user?

Comment: Not a Kali author, but Firefox updates have a tendency to disable add-ons, so if Kali's FF comes with specific add-ons (which would not be too surprising given Kali's goals), remaining on a stable release could prevent many problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that Kali is based on Debian *Testing* and Debian includes Firefox ESR due to its expected stability benefits.

[Kali and Debian](https://docs.kali.org/policy/kali-linux-relationship-with-debian)

On security differences:

There's not necessarily any security problems with the Standard Edition Firefox versus the Extended Support Release.  The difference lies in the stability of the code base.  So, the ESR version is expected to be more reliable over time.  However, there may be security problems in a Standard Edition which will never be patched for that edition.  It's *expected* stability vs. *possible unfixed* breakage.

See: [Firefox ESR webpage](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/)

On Kali Linux questions in general:

Kali is a very specialized distro.  It is not meant for general purpose use.

See: [why is kali linux so hard to set up why wont people help me](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: Conversely it wouldn't be that hard for Kali to change this default. So xenoids explanation for example still holds merit.